# Is HTTP 1.1 Full duplex?

Tags: http

wondering whether any one can provide a convincing explanation about the whether HTTP 1.1 is half duplex or full duplex in the context of pipelining? As far as I understand,multiple requests can be send over the same persistent connection before the client gets the response.  So does that mean that server can respond for the previous request while client sends a new request?

Comment: This is not a programming question (it's a question about a network protocol). StackOverflow is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions. The [help] has more details about the types of questions that are proper to ask here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's have a look at the standard, in this case [RFC-2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).  There we find in paragraph 8.1.1, Persistent connections:

```
  - HTTP requests and responses can be pipelined on a connection.
    Pipelining allows a client to make multiple requests without
    waiting for each response, allowing a single TCP connection to
    be used much more efficiently, with much lower elapsed time.
```

and a bit later in the document:

```
8.1.2.2 Pipelining

   A client that supports persistent connections MAY "pipeline" its
   requests (i.e., send multiple requests without waiting for each
   response). A server MUST send its responses to those requests in the
   same order that the requests were received.
```

As in both cases it's clearly stated that the client can send requests without waiting for a response, I think it's safe to state that HTTP 1.1 supports full-duplex.

EDIT: in [RFC-7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.3.2), part of the RFC set that replaces RFC-2616, this statement becomes:

```
A client that supports persistent connections MAY "pipeline" its
requests (i.e., send multiple requests without waiting for each
response).  A server MAY process a sequence of pipelined requests in
parallel if they all have safe methods (Section 4.2.1 of [RFC7231]),
but it MUST send the corresponding responses in the same order that
the requests were received.
```

Comment: Isn't vijayst's definition the correct one for "full duplex"? Even with pipelining, HTTP 1.1 is not a full duplex connection right?

Comment: @user487478 I don't agree with his explanation and neither does Julian Reschke, one of the authors of RFC 7230...

Comment: HTTP is definitely half-duplex except the case of WebSockets. An HTTP Server never sends arbitrary notifications instead of responses to requests. This holds true for HTTP/1.1 with Pipelining and HTTP/2 with Server-Push as well.

Comment: @ErsinEr bad answers definitely need to be voted down. However, your understanding of 'full duplex' is relative to the layer *on top* of http. In the case of pipelining, a server can send responses while the client is sending requests, proving it's fullduplex. I have no idea why you think that the absence of arbitrary notifications makes http half duplex...  vijayst's phone analogy has the same issue: when we're on the phone we're not required to listen to and react to the other party - we both can make noise and "both noises" will be transmitted.

Comment: It really doesn't matter if multiple request can be sent without waiting for the first response to arrive. It still may mean that at any given moment connection can be handling either only sending a request or receiving a response, which would make it half-duplex, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: But the server can't initiate a message to the client, it can only respond after it has received a request. To me that means it's not full duplex.

Comment: @JuanPerez you seem to be confounding the request-reply mechanism with full duplex: full duplex *only* means that data can flow in both directions simultaneously, simple as that. Really :-)

Answer (score 26):

HTTP is request-response protocol. The client sends request. The server waits till the complete request is received. Then sends a response. The client and server cannot send simultaneously.

Full Duplex channel implies that client and server can send data simultaneously. Phone lines are example of Full Duplex. To achieve full duplex in Web, Web sockets is the recommended standard. Once a Web socket connection is established, both parties can exchange messages simultaneously. Web sockets work on top of TCP and does not use the HTTP protocol.

Comment: The server doesn't need to wait for the whole request, nor does the client need to wait for the server's reply before proceeding.

Answer (score 3):

Most implementations do allow full-duplex HTTP (for 2xx responses).

A formal discussion can be found at

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zhu-http-fullduplex

Answer (score 1):

As it is using tcp, that doesn't mean every application protocol on tcp is a full duplex.

HTTP uses a request-response paradigm, not a full-duplex streaming paradigm. Let me repeat it: HTTP is a request-response protocol! This means that the client sends a request, and when the complete request has been sent then the server sends the response. This is the case even if so-called keep-alive is used, i.e. multiple requests are sent over the same TCP connection. Because this behaviour is fundamental to the protocol most implementations make certain (valid) assumptions which make it difficult to create a full-duplex connection.

If you want a full duplex go for websockets, which are designed for an entirely different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications)

Half-duplex:

> In a half-duplex or semiduplex system, both parties can communicate
> with each other, but not simultaneously; the communication is one
> direction at a time.

Full-duplex:

> In a full-duplex system, both parties can communicate with each other
> simultaneously. An example of a full-duplex device is plain old
> telephone service; the parties at both ends of a call can speak and be
> heard by the other party simultaneously.

Therefore, HTTP is NOT fully duplex.